# Move hard drive from macbook pro to macbook air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive

I have a Macbook Pro with a 250 GB SSD hard drive (Macbook retina Mid 2012 i7) and a Macbook air with 120 GB SSD hard drive (Mid 2012 Intel Core i5).

I would like to move the swap the hard drives if the hardware is compatible.
Is this possible? Is it just a matter of opening the machines and swapping the hard drives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see both MacBook's using different SSD's. Take a look on [iFixit.com](http://www.iFixit.com) and the image taken from the tutorial

**MacBook Air 13" Mid 2012 Solid-State Drive**
[image: MacBook Air 13" Mid 2012 Solid-State Drive Replacement].

**MacBook Pro 15" Retina Display Mid 2012 SSD**
[image: MacBook Pro 15" Retina Display Mid 2012 SSD Replacement]

[MacBook Pro 15" Retina Display Mid 2012 SSD Replacement](https://de.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2012+SSD+Replacement/9706?lang=en)
[MacBook Air 13" Mid 2012 Solid-State Drive Replacement](https://de.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2012+Solid-State+Drive+Replacement/10961?lang=en)

I guess it would be much easier and faster using Time Machine, Superduper, Disk Utility, CCC...